# Select a specified subset of vertices distributed on a circle

Tags: graphs-and-networks

A [circular embedding](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularEmbedding.html) is a graph embedding in which all graph vertices lie on a common circle, usually arranged so they are equally spaced around the circumference.

If I only specify that some of the vertices are on a circle while the others are placed inside the circle (or arranged randomly), how should I handle it? For example,

```
    TrapezohedralGraph[n_] :=
     Module[{c}, c = CycleGraph[n]; VertexAdd[c, {n + 1, n + 2}]; 
      EdgeAdd[c, 
       Flatten[{Table[n + 1 <-> i, {i, 1, n, 2}], 
         Table[n + 2 <-> i, {i, 2, n, 2}]}]]]
TrapezohedralGraph[20]
```

[image]

But I love the following embedding from the web [Trapezohedral Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrapezohedralGraph.html):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option `VertexCoordinates` to place the first `n` vertices on the unit circle and the last two vertices on a smaller circle.

Use the second argument in `trapezohedralGraph` to specify the horizontal coordinate of last two vertices.

```
trapezohedralGraph = Graph[TrapezohedralGraph[#], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Join[ CirclePoints[#], CirclePoints[#2, 2]], ##3] &;

trapezohedralGraph[20, .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define `trapezohedronGraph` as `GraphUnion` of `CycleGraph` and two `StarGraph`s (one with odd vertices and the second with even vertices):

```
ClearAll[trapezohedronGraph]

trapezohedronGraph = GraphUnion[
  CycleGraph @ #,
  Map[Splice@Thread[Most@# <-> Last @ #] &] @ {#, # + 1} & @ Range[1, # + 2, 2],
  VertexCoordinates -> Join[ CirclePoints[#], CirclePoints[#2, 2]], ##3] &;

Multicolumn[
 trapezohedronGraph[#, .3, VertexStyle -> Red, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ 
  Range[4, 22, 2], 5, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

Add the option

```
EdgeShapeFunction ->
   (GraphComputation`GraphElementData[
   {"CurvedArc", 
    "Curvature" -> ((1/3) Sign[#[[1, 1]]] Order @@ #[[{1, -1}, 2]])}][##] &)
```

to get

[image]